# Patches over original source - Choosing strategy

Tags: git

There is some git repo that's upgrading almost everyday.

I need to modify some of the core functions, plenty of them, but don't know how to avoid doing conflict-solving merges by hand every time original repo is changed.

Is there's some optimal practice available?

Comment: If you're updating the core of something that's changing everyday, there is going to be pain no matter how you go about it. To limit the pain, you can very often fetch changes and rebase your feature branch. If you need to solve the same conflicts regulary, you can have a look at `rerere`: https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html

Comment: @SébastienDawans Sounds like a good idea! Thanks for reply. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep there is a way to auto-resolve conflicts in GIT. Its called `git rerere`

> rerere = **Re**use **Re**corded **Re**solution

When enabled the rerere simply "record" the way you resolved the conflict (creating patch file) and this file will be used to auto merge the same conflict when git see it again.

As best practice if you know in advance that you are going to do a massive refactor of old code - you should do it in small chunks as mush as possible in order to bypass the massive merges later on.

Read more [here](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html)

Comment: Thanks for advice regarding small chunks! I need to learn rerere for sure. =)